# UNIX Bash: Number each line of a file with a specific format

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to number each line of a file with this format:  `/1/`,`/2/`,...

For example

From

```
UK
Australia
Newzealand
Brazil
America
```

To

```
/1/ UK
/2/ Australia
/3/ Newzealand
/4/ Brazil
/5/ America
```

I think about

```
grep -n file.txt // but the format is 1: , 2: , ...
nl file.txt  // but the format is 1 , 2 , 3
```

Can i give a specific format to `nl` command?

Comment: With awk: `awk '{print "/" NR "/ " $0}' file`

Comment: Maybe `Perl` is acceptable to the professor... `perl -pe 'print "/$./ "' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU cat and GNU sed:

```
cat -n file | sed 's|^ *|/|;s|\t|/ |'
```

Output:

```
/1/ UK
/2/ Australia
/3/ Newzealand
/4/ Brazil
/5/ America
```

---

I used two `s` commands with this format: `s|regexp|replacement|`.

> `s|^ *|/|`: This replaces in a line starting (`^`) with zero or more (`*`) blanks by a `/`
>
> `s|\t|/ |`: This Replaces a tab (`\t`) by a slash followed by a blank.

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: In the same lines as yours, `cat -n file | while read number line; do printf "/%d/ %s\n" "$number" "$line"; done`

Comment: I like this answer. Can you please explain me how this substitution is working here `^ *` and `\t` in stream editor command?

Comment: @Inian  Unfortunately yes, because of my Professor. I have to do it without awk, but with commands like sed, nl, ...

Comment: Thankyou so much for the explanations. I now understand.  There are many others alternatives, but this is my best. +1

Answer (score 4):

Use the `printf` function in `Awk`, with the characters `/` around the integer part.

```
awk '{printf("/%d/ %s\n", NR, $0)}' file
/1/ UK
/2/ Australia
/3/ Newzealand
/4/ Brazil
/5/ America
```

`NR` is a special variable in `awk` which tracks the record number of each line as it is processed, and the line as such being `$0`. The above command is `POSIX` compatible since `awk` in all major platforms support `printf` with format specifiers.

A proper way to do it in `bash` alone, without any third-party tools.

```
#!/bin/bash

count=1
while IFS= read -r line
do
  printf "/%d/ %s\n" "$count" "$line"
  ((count++))
done <input-file
```

AFAIK, from the `man nl` page, there are options you can use, but **NONE** to wrap the line numbers around the characters you want, you can of-course use it one side, with `-s` flag

The closest I could do with it is,

```
nl -nrz -s/ -w1 file
1/UK
2/Australia
3/Newzealand
4/Brazil
5/America
```

here, `-nrz` for right justification and `-s` for the special character to use after the numbering done. In this case, I have a added a `/` and `-w` controls the width of the numbering part.

Comment: note: there is also  FNR, which is a separate counter per file.

Comment: Your answer is working perfectly. But for an academical purpose i have to do it without the `awk` command. Does it have another method?

Comment: With small simplifications (without `count=1`): `while IFS= read -r line; do printf "/%d/ %s\n" "$((++count))" "$line"; done <file`

Comment: This solution ist great. But unfortunately i wanted a simple method without `awk`. Thanks for help. +1

Comment: Why is a pipeline involving `cat` and `sed` preferable to a single `awk` command?

Comment: @chepner: Yup ,sounded weird, stopped my argument when I saw _because of my Professor. I have to do it without awk_ in one of the comments above. :)

Comment: Alternative version `awk '{print "/"NR"/", $0}'  file`